# Finding a specific solution to $X^T\Sigma X = D$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convexity, multilinear-algebra

I'm looking to solve for a specific $X$ in the following equation:
$$X^T\Sigma X = D,$$
where $\Sigma \succ 0$, $D$ is a diagonal matrix with strictly positive entries, and all matrices are square. It may also be worth noting that $\det(\Sigma) = \det(D)$.

I'm looking for a (known to exist) solution $X$ which can be written as $I-W$, where $W$ is permutation-similar to a strictly-triangular matrix. Using Sylvester's Law of Inertia, I'm able to solve for an $X$ (up to a unitary transformation) by finding the transformation which converts $\Sigma$ and $D$ to the same diagonal matrix (since they both have all positive entries). However, I don't know how to take this solution to one that matches the form I-W as described above.

Alternatively, I've also considered how one might solve this with the solution to a convex program, but haven't had much success so far.

Comment: One solution is obtainable via $X^T\sqrt \Sigma  = \sqrt D$ (so $X^T = \sqrt D\Sigma^{-1}$). Here the $\sqrt \centerdot$ refers to the unique positive definite one (since $\Sigma$ has to be invertible). Then you can through in a unitary, $X^T\sqrt \Sigma  = (\sqrt D)U$, and obtain all of them (I think).

Comment: And by "one", I meant "square root"; by "through", I meant "throw".

Comment: Is $det(\Sigma)=det(D)$ an additional constraint? How does it follow from $X^\top \Sigma X=D$, unless you seeking a a solution with a unit determinant?